# How to run some alias command in bash's non-interactive mode for Ubuntu

Tags: bash, command-line, alias

I want to run some alias command in bash's non-interactive mode. But seems Ubuntu ignore BAHS_ENV. How can I make it work? `la` is a alias command. And I tested in other linux. it is work fine. Just Ubuntu not work.

`BASH_ENV=~/.profile bash -O expand_aliases -c la`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just logged in an Ubuntu box (12.04.1), and it works fine:

Create a file `test_bash_env` that contains the following script:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "This is a test for BASH_ENV, the value of which is: \`$BASH_ENV'"
```

Then, we happily have:

```
gniourf@ubuntubox:~/Test$ BASH_ENV=./test_bash_env bash -c 'echo "Hello, BASH_ENV!"'
This is a test for BASH_ENV, the value of which is: `./test_bash_env'
Hello, BASH_ENV!
```

Did you mispell a variable or something?

Comment: Thanks ~ gniourf ~ yes it's work ~ just found out because the origin .bashrc provided by Ubuntu have some code like below to prevent the script run in non-interactive mode. so why my alias not work. It's work now just need to move aliases higher then this block

`# If not running interactively, don't do anything
case $- in
    *i*) ;;
      *) return;;
esac`